# C# Generic List.Any() throws System.NullReferenceException

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, generic-list

Consider the following partial view code snippet

```
List<sellingPrice> Prices = ViewBag.Prices;
foreach (var mgmp in mg.messageGroup.messageGroupMessagePLUs)
{
    if (Prices.Any(x => x.pluId == mgmp.messagePLU.plu.pluId))
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

For specific products in the db, the line

```
if (Prices.Any(x => x.pluId == mgmp.messagePLU.plu.pluId))
```

throws a System.NullReferenceException. Inspecting the code shows that mgmp ***is*** an object and Prices contains elements. However, the value of x is null. Now, I am under the impression that I am simply testing whether or not any "x" exists that satisfies my test, not asking it to return an "x".

It's a very irritating problem. Hopefully someone can point out the really obvious solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
Prices.Any(x => x!=null && x.pluId == mgmp.messagePLU.plu.pluId)
```

You might need to do other null checks if for example .messagePLU can be null

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks. I didn't think it would be necessary in my case to test for nulls in my Prices collection. Ah well, you live and learn.

Comment: One thing to note is that this might only work wit linq-to-objects where the order is guaranteed. I'm not 100% sure but think linq-to-SQL might not short circuit correctly.

Comment: We'll cross that bridge when we get there.

Comment: You can now use null propagation like `(x?.pluId == mgmp.messagePLU?.plu.pluId)`.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason why this happens is because one or more items in the `ViewBag.Prices` is `null`. Check `x` for `null`, or see why prices contain `null`s in the first place, assuming it's not supposed to have any `null` values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for reasoning.
An extension to check for list.Any() any even if List is null.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the collection is null or contains no elements.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The IEnumerable type.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="enumerable">The enumerable, which may be null or empty.</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///     <c>true</c> if the IEnumerable is null or empty; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </returns>
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this ICollection<T> enumerable)
    {
        return enumerable != null && enumerable.Count > 0;
    }
```